# Lied on resume & app but told truth in the interview & background check

Tags: resume, job-offer, background-check, hiring

So when I applied, I said on the app that I had completed my masters. Actually my coursework is complete & I need to finish research, but I left because the funding was insufficient. Stupid, I know. I interviewed and we didn’t talk about education much (my masters is irrelevant for the job), but I did say I left academics for financial reasons. I realized my mistake the day after interview & resubmitted my application with the correct info, but I’m not sure if they got it.

Now they offered me the job, contingent on background and drug testing. I put the correct info on the remaining forms. HR asked me to bring in my “college diploma” when I come in with all my documents (standard procedure), but one of the pre-filled forms mentioned my grad school & not my undergrad. So I emailed to point out that the info about the undergrad institution was missing. And on the phone I told her I’d be bringing in my diploma from LSU (undergrad) because “that’s where I got my degree.” She said that was fine, they just needed any diploma.

I’m trying to be honest with them. Is it too late?

Answer (score 6):

> I’m trying to be honest with them. Is it too late?

Short answer, **it might be**, but....

If I make sense of the scenario, it appears that they are only interested in a college degree, which you have.  Bring it in as instructed and **don't bring up anything else**.  It looks like in this case *your gaff went un-noticed*.

For the future, **never lie** to a potential employer about your credentials or capabilities.  For that matter, life is much easier if you don't lie at all.  Not meant to be a lecture, just sharing my experience.